# How transactions can be managed in a micro-service architecture

Tags: transactions, microservices

I have multiple microservice say A, B, and C. A is the starting service that performs some operations and triggers B's endpoint which performs some operation and calls C's endpoint. If something goes wrong at C, all other means A and B work should be rolled back.

A few days ago I heard about using the SAGA pattern to achieve this, is there any SAGA implementation available in the market? Or any other approach to handle this scenario.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question as it stands is unlikely to attract a good answer and so will probably be closed. Questions should relate to specific programming problems. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check out the Axon framework. See https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/complex-business-transactions/implementing-saga

Comment: Thanks, @Micahael. This article looks interesting.